# Regex for checking a letter-only string without "="

Tags: regex

How can I check via regex if a string is:
- letters-only (a-z, insensitive)
- does not have an equal sign

ex.

- `class` - should pass
- `class="something"` - should fail
- `class=someclass` - should fail

So far I have this:

```
[a-zA-Z][^=]+
```

However when I tested it on regex101 with
`class=someclass`
It results with:

```
 - Match 1 - Full match 0-5 class
 - Match 2 - Full match  6-15 someclass
```

What am I missing here?
Thanks!

Comment: Why not just `^[a-z]+$`?

Comment: The input is HTML ?

Comment: @GillesQuenot yes, vue/html attributes. I am using the regex to sort the attributes using this VS Code extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rbalet.vscode-sorting-attrs. And the order is configured via regex: https://github.com/mrmlnc/posthtml-attrs-sorter#order. Basically I need a regex for single-word keywords (for vue, without any characters, specifically the = sign).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to wrap your solution with `^` and `$` to force it to match against the full line, rather than searching for matches within the line. This assumes the multiline flag is enabled, which should be the default on regex101.

Proof: https://regex101.com/r/2aYZF1/1

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly anchor the regex with `/^...$/`. Here is a working snippet that takes your examples:

```js
var str1 = 'class';
var str2 = 'class="something"';
var str3 = 'class=something';
var re = /^[a-z]+$/i;
var result1 = re.test(str1);
var result2 = re.test(str2);
var result3 = re.test(str3);
console.log('- result1: ' + result1);
console.log('- result2: ' + result2);
console.log('- result3: ' + result3);
```

Result:

```
- result1: true
- result2: false
- result3: false
```